# Load an iframe in Colorbox when click on an image

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, gallery, colorbox

I have two plugins: [Tiles Gallery](http://codecanyon.net/item/final-tiles-gallery/4734090) and [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) - a very basic gallery setup, click on a thumbnail -> load full size in Colorbox. However, I would like to be able to click on a gallery image and load a webpage in an iframe in the Colorbox pop-up.

Here is how regular gallery items/images are loaded (works perfectly):

```
<article class="tile category">
   <a href="path/to/image.jpg">
     <img class="item" src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" />
     <div class="caption"></div>
   </a>
</article>
```

And here is how I unsuccessfully try to load the iframe:

```
<article class="tile iframe" data-type="html">
  <a class="tile iframe" href="http://google.com">
  <img class="item" src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" />
  </a>
</article>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
    //instantiate Final Tiles Gallery
    $("#gallery-name").finalTilesGallery({
        minTileWidth: 120,
        margin: 1,
    });
    // colorbox image size setup
    $(".tile a").colorbox({rel:'group1', maxWidth:'95%', maxHeight:'95%'
    }); 
    // colorbox iframe setup
    $(".tile iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:600, innerHeight:700});

</script>
```

Each  has to have a class "tile *something*" in order for the Tiles gallery plugin to work. According to the Tiles gallery documentation, YouTube videos are loaded using iframe the following way:

```
<article id="video" class="tile ftg-set-2" data-type="video">
 <iframe class="item" width="540" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M4yCwlDxPtY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</article>
```

however I don't want the iframe to be displayed in the gallery itself, I want a thumbnail image to lead to it and only to display it in Colorbox.

Let me know if you need any more information. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to select using $(".tile iframe")?  In jQuery this will grab the elements with tagName "iframe" which descend from an element with class "tile", which does not relate to any elements in your markup.  See this fiddle for a demo of the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/R2vHD/

Comment: @AaronK thans for your comment. I should have explained further. $(".tile iframe") is used to grab my <article> with class "tile iframe", my other "tile" <article>s are called with different names. the "tile" class is a requiremenent of the Tiles plugin.

Comment: Okay, to grab the article try using $(".tile.iframe"), $(".tile iframe") won't work for an article item

Comment: ohh! thanks, that solved part of the problem :) Now it won't load the actual web page, and the thumbnail looks a bit weird, but still - I'm half way there. Thank you and sorry for not understanding what you meant in the first comment :)

Comment: @LPetkov: You still need help solving everything?

Comment: @Jean-Paul nope - managed to solve the problem, just forgot to answer the question here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem like this:

```
      <article class="tile category">
            <a class="className" href="http://iframe-address.com">
                <img class="item" src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" />
                <div class="caption"></div>
             </a>
    </article>
```

jquery:

```
    $(".className").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:'99%', innerHeight:'99%'});
```